# how to center a title and shade the complete line that contains it in PhpWord

Tags: php, phpword

I try with this: `$phpWord->addTitleStyle(1, array('size' => 12, 'Arial' => true,'bold' => true,'align'=>'center','bgColor' => 'fbbb10'));`

```
$section->addTitle('GOBERNADOR', 1);
```

but it does not center the text and only the part of the text not all the line is shaded

Comment: I could center it with this: `[ 'align' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\TextAlignment::CENTER ]` 
but how could I fill in the whole line??

Comment: and with this: `$phpWord->addTitleStyle(1, array('size' => 12, 'Arial' => true,'bold' => true), array('shading' => array('fill' => '00FF00')),[ 'align' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\TextAlignment::CENTER ]);` it fills the whole line but does not center it